# How to set value to declared variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequences

How to set value to declared variable in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE  @V_SEQUENCE INT,  @V_SEQUENCENAME NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @V_SEQUENCENAME = 'dbo.MYSEQ';   
EXEC('SELECT @V_SEQUENCE = NEXT VALUE FOR  ' + @V_SEQUENCENAME)
SELECT @V_SEQUENCE
```

Here i am getting an error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@V_SEQUENCE"'

Please tell me how to get result of `@V_SEQUENCE`.

Comment: If sequence name is constant then you don't need dynamic sql.

Comment: Sequence name is Dynamic, Just for example I have mentioned static name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to pass a value out of the execute.  I recommend that you use `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE  @V_SEQUENCE INT, @V_SEQUENCENAME NVARCHAR(MAX), @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @V_SEQUENCENAME = 'dbo.MYSEQ'; 
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT @V_SEQUENCE = NEXT VALUE FOR  ' + @V_SEQUENCENAME;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@V_SEQUENCE INT OUTPUT', @V_SEQUENCE = @V_SEQUENCE OUTPUT;

SELECT @V_SEQUENCE;
```

Comment: Thank you, Now I am getting expected results.